# Parametrized nested erb components in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, erb

I'm quite new with Rails, but have React experience. I'd like to manage with erb files sth I could do in React that way:

```
class MyElement extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      some text
      {this.props.myFirstParam + this.props.mySecondParam}
      some another text
    </div>
  }
}

class MyBody extends Component {
  render() {
    return <body>
      <MyElement myFirstParam={1} mySecondParam={2} />
      <MyElement myFirstParam={3} mySecondParam={5} />
      <MyElement myFirstParam={7} mySecondParam={3} />
    </body>
  }
}
```

Of course I know that Rails process files on the server side, but I'd like just to show the idea of component nesting. I'd like to avoid imperative string concatenation in methods too. Is there some good way to do this?

Comment: have you looked at this?  https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails

Comment: I think I was misunderstood. I DON'T want to use React. I'd just like to do with Rails the same I can easily do with React, but without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the way. We can do this with `render` function. I created file named `_my_element.erb` which looks like this:

```
<div>
  some text
  <%= myFirstParam + mySecondParam %>
  some another text
</div>
```

It's located in `views` folder, which seems to be important.

Next in `my_body` file I inserted:

```
<%= render partial: "my_element.erb",
    locals: {myFirstParam: 1, mySecondParam: 2} %>
```

For some reason name of file should begins with `_` char, while path in `partial` parameter should't include it.

But after all, that works.

Answer (score 0):

You've given your own solution already, but let me add a cleaner apporach to what you might be after.

If you've followed the Rails pattern your `MyBodyController#show`-method sets `@my_body` and your `MyBody` has a `has_many :my_elements` line. You can now type:

```
<%= render @my_body.my_elements %>
```

You can now create a 'my_elements/_my_element.html.erb'-file (yep indeed with that underscore) that can contain the HTML for rendering the comment block (if you do this step wrong, Rails will explain you what to do). Since it is a set of records the code will repeated for all comments.

As a more general note: In Rails you typically pass objects (with values, but also methods), instead of just the limited set of separate values needed for rendering that element.

See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables